# Render actual HTML image

Tags: html, image

In an html file for my first (very basic) blog site, I am able to successfully show the blog title, blog poster's name, the date it was published and also a short summary of the actual blog text with the following HTML:

```
<h2><a class="card-title" href="  {{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_post', blog_post_id=post.blog_id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
<a href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}">Written By: {{ post.author.username }}</a>

<p>Published on: {{ post.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</p>
<p class="card-text">{{ post.text[:150] }}...</p>
<a href="{{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_post', blog_post_id=post.blog_id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read Blog Post</a>
```

However, I'd like to display a picture of the author's (users) profile picture next after the author's username, which is shown above on the second line.

What I've attempted to do is add this snippet of code:

```
<p> {{post.author.profile_image}} </p>
```

as this is the actual profile image from the posting author as I've already defined. Though I realize this is a paragraph and not actually an image. How do I convert the line of code above into something that actually renders their profile image? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using Twig? If not, then what template engine do you use?

Comment: I’m using SublimeText and then got a Heroku site up and going. If that’s what you’re asking I’m not sure

Comment: What is wrong with the `<img src="....">` tag?

Comment: And I think @LajosArpad was asking if you are using a framework like Angular, Twig etc. to generate the final html as `{{ }}` etc. are not in the standard HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

instead of

```
<p> {{post.author.profile_image}} </p>
```

use

```
<img src={{post.author.profile_image}} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).